# Marking current locations keeps giving the coordinates 0,0

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-location

I am using Google Maps service for an app I am making using Xcode 9.2 and Swift 4. When I press a button I would like my current location to be marked on the map view with a marker above it. Instead, when tapping the button it takes me to the coordinates 0,0. What am I doing wrong? Thank you for all your help in advance.

```
//Location Manager

var userLocation = CLLocation()

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

userLocation = locations.last!

let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: userLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: userLocation.coordinate.longitude, zoom: 14);
self.googleMapsView.camera = camera

//Finally stop updating location otherwise it will come again and again in this delegate

self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

}

//Button Marker Function

@IBAction func markCurrentLocation(_ sender: UIButton) {

let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: userLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: userLocation.coordinate.longitude)

    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: userLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: userLocation.coordinate.longitude, zoom: 14);
    self.googleMapsView.camera = camera
    self.googleMapsView.isMyLocationEnabled = true

    let marker = GMSMarker(position: center)

    print("Latitude :- \(userLocation.coordinate.latitude)")
    print("Longitude :-\(userLocation.coordinate.longitude)")

    marker.map = self.googleMapsView

    marker.title = "Current Location"

    googleMapsView.animate(to: camera)

    //Finally stop updating location otherwise it will come again and again in this delegate

    self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
}
```

Comment: You created let userLocation = CLLocation(), and it is empty. Instead you should implement corelocation delegate methods to pinpoint devices location

Comment: Please read the [Location and Maps Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/Introduction/Introduction.html) to learn how to get a user's current location.

Comment: I think you are testing it on simulator, please enable current location for simulator, or test it on Real device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will return 0 because you created a new CLLocation() instance with nothing in it.
Get the current location from the [locationManager(_:didUpdateLocations:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanagerdelegate/1423615-locationmanager) delegate.

Do it like:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    userLocation = locations.last
}
```

And remove `let userLocation = CLLocation()` from your `markCurrentLocation(_:)` method

Also be sure to add request in your info.plist
[image]

Comment: Yes but I want to use the variable within the button's action which means I have to use 'var userLocation = CLLocation()' outside of the function as well correct?

Comment: Yes, you can define it as a global variable.

Comment: so I did that but it is still giving me the coordinates 0,0

Comment: I just updated the code above... if you wouldn't mind taking a look at it and letting me know if anything still seems wrong that would be awesome

Comment: There is no need to call self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation() in your button. You already stopped the location updates in the locationManager().

Comment: Please check my updated answer. You also need to ask permission in the info.plist